# How to increment results of an Api Pagininated response on scroll in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

i have i a component on scroll of bottom i need to increment the results of an api data but as total Results will be dynamic and when we reach the total Results count i dont want to call the increment results , stop api fetching and set loader to false,but api keeps calling again and again even if reach the total results count.

```
const initialState = {
 resultsData: [],

  resultsPerPage: 3,
  totalResults: null,
  loader: true,
}
```

Action

```
export const set_Results = (value) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: SET_RESULTS_PERPAGE, payload: value });
  };
};
```

```
const getTotalResults = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.results.totalResults;
  });

 const getresultsData = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.results.resultsData;
  });
```

Reducer

```
case SET_RESULTS_PERPAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        resultsPerPage: action.payload,
      };
```

dispatch

```
const loaderAndScroll = () => {
    if (getresultsData.length < getTotalResults) {
      return getResultsPerPage + 3;
    }
  };

 const scrollToEnd = (event) => {
    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = event.currentTarget;

    if (scrollHeight - scrollTop === clientHeight) {
      dispatch(set_Results(loaderAndScroll()));
    
    }
  };
```